# Interpolate an object from rest API

Tags: mysql, angular, rest, spring-data-jpa, string-interpolation

hello I'm having trouble on how to interpolate the object from rest API, I can see the objects in console log but I can't bind it in a label to my table

this is the object I want to interpolate in my table

clerk:
name: "May Anne"
[[Prototype]]: Object

this is my service.ts

```
//fetch discounte Bill
  fetchDiscountedBill(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/discountedBill');
  }
```

this is the model.ts

```
 export class BillingModel{
        clerk : {
            name: string;
        }
    }
```

I call the model.ts to my table.component.ts with this

```
billingModel: BillingModel = {
      clerk: {
        name: ''
      }
    };
```

and create a method with this

```
 getDiscountedBill(){
        this.dataStorageService.fetchDiscountedBill().subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp)
          this.billingModel = data;;
        }, err => {
          console.log(err)
        });
      }
```

and this is the label I want to interpolate or bind the object

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="4">Attending Clerk: </td>
    </tr>
```

Please help thank you!

Comment: don't post pictures of code.  edit the question and post as text, and post a [mcve]

Comment: I already edited it thanks

Comment: What is `data` in `this.billingModel = data;`? Also what is the data structure of the HTTP response?

Comment: this is the data shows in the console log -- {orderList: Array(4), clerk: {…}, totalbill: 0}
clerk: {name: 'May Anne'}
orderList: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
totalbill: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object -- i just wanted to get the object clerk and its name only and bind it in my table

Comment: In ts file `this.billingModel.clerk = resp.clerk` and in html you can display name as `{{billingModel?.clerk?.name}}`

Comment: Hi @Siddhant, can you post the solution as an answer, so the Post owner can accept the answer and resolve the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ts file within subscribe, you can assign the value as:

```ts
this.billingModel.clerk = resp.clerk;
```

and then display the clerk name within your html template using [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) as:

```html
{{billingModel?.clerk?.name}}
```

If your HTTP response data structure matches your defined model, then you can use the same type in your service class method as:

```ts
fetchDiscountedBill(): Observable<BillingModel> {
    return this.http.get<BillingModel>(this.baseUrl + '/discountedBill');
}
```

and within subscribe you can simply do:

```ts
this.billingModel = resp;
```

Also when defining your model, you don't need to define it as a `class`, but can define it as an interface:

```ts
export interface BillingModel {
    clerk: {
        name: string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this.BillingModel.clerk = resp.clerk in component method

Comment: it still doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

i also have same issue data show in console but not show in table

and one think what name of  array show  in console that name write in ts  like that res['name of array']

**try this**

```
 getDiscountedBill(){
        this.dataStorageService.fetchDiscountedBill().subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp)
          this.billingModel = res['orderList']; <==  not work then try below  ;
          this.billingModel = res['clerk']; <== this will work 
          this.billingModel = res['clerk'].name; <== if you want to display name of clerk then try this

        }, err => {
          console.log(err)
        });
  }
```